# React-native - Dropdownpicker - undefined is not an object(evaluating 'choice.label')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[I use DropDownPicker in react-native , When page loading i got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndm5n.png)

I use a DropDownPicker as follows :

```
                    <DropDownPicker
                        items={[
                          { label: 'Us', value: 'Us' },
                          { label: 'Canada, value: 'Canada' }
                        ]}
                        defaultValue={this.state.country}
                        containerStyle={{ height: 40 }}
                        style={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                        itemStyle={{
                          justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                        }}
                        dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                        onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
                        country: item.value
                        })}
                      />
```

Comment: I can see a typo at your item Object  ```{ label: 'Canada, value: 'Canada' }``` should be ```{ label: 'Canada', value: 'Canada' }```

Comment: If there answer below fixes your issue you should accept it, otherwise provide further information in the comment section

Comment: I have same error, but my json is valid

items={[
                { label: 'USA', value: 'usa' },
                { label: 'UK', value: 'uk' },
                { label: 'France', value: 'france' },
              ]}

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `'` with the word Canada:

```js
items={[
   { label: 'Us', value: 'Us' },
   { label: 'Canada', value: 'Canada' }
]}
```

**Reading Debug Messages**

The `choice.label` error is a good hint that something is wrong with a label property being passed to `DropDownPicker`. Going forward definitely look out for little hints like this to help guide you to a solution.